# How do you set the current user in an ASP.NET MVC 5 application using ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am having difficulty figuring out how to set the current user in an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that uses ASP.NET Identity.

We use a Web Service that encapsulates authentication. A function calls that service and gets back a JWT token that can be "unwrapped" to retrieve the `ClaimsIdentity`. It's my understanding that all you should need to do, at that point, is call `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn()` and pass the `ClaimsIdentity` to establish the current user and get that user to persist across requests.

However, this doesn't seem to be the case. If I query `this.User` in the controller or the view afterwards, it's an anonymous user (`this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` evaluates to `false`). Also, refreshing the page or redirecting makes it obvious that there's no current user (again, `this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` evaluates to `false`).

When I inspect the identity I've retrieved from `AccountHelper`, all the data is there. It's fully populated with a name, an ID, and a full suite of claims.

So what is the right way to establish the current user and get it to persist across requests?

```
// This call authenticates a user with the provided credentials against our user store
// and returns a bearer token and a ClaimsIdentity.
var response = new AccountHelper().AuthenticateUser(credentials);

if (response.IsAuthenticated) // This is true
{
    // This comes back with a fully populated identity, as expected.
    var claimsIdentity = response.ClaimsIdentity; 

    // This call has no effect, whatsoever. It doesn't set the current user.
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
               .Authentication
               .SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true }, claimsIdentity);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, did you miss `.Current` in your code sample?

It should be

```cs
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
    .Authentication
    .SignIn(...);
```

Secondly, I'm assuming you've setup cookie authentication in your app?

```cs
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
    ...
});
```

Here setting the authentication type is important! And when you generate the claims identity and before you pass it into the `.SignIn()` method, the claims identity needs to have the same authentication type so that they can talk!

I would use `.CreateIdentityAsync()` method from the `UserManager` class to create the identity instead, because you can pass the authentication type in as one of the parameters:

```cs
// Create an application user from your claim identity?
var appUser = new AppUser { ... };

// And pass the user into manager to create the identity with the same authentication
// type you used when you setup the cookie authentication
var claimsIdentity = _userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(appUser,
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

I am using this way to impersonate users for admins that have developer role so that we can test the app.

Comment: It turned out that we were, in fact, missing the configuration info in our Startup.Auth. When I added it, it worked. But then we discovered that this application is actually using two different identity providers (AAD and OAUTH) and that the in-house developers never accounted for this scenario. They assumed things were peachy with OATH everywhere. When I added the missing entries, I overwrote the default authentication type, and things worked. Good for me, bad for them. Havoc ensues.